# Открытие портов android

Tags: android, ssh, port, termux

Пытаюсь открыть порты на android 8, но не знаю как это сделать.Я хочу запустить ssh сервер в termux(что бы можно было подключится из вне).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открывать не нужно, у меня из коробки все работает (просто порт не дефолтный 22).

На Android:

1. `pkg upgrade`
2. `pkg install openssh` - установить OpenSSH
3. `sshd` - запустить сервер
4. `whoami` - выведет имя пользователя с ним и нужно будет подключаться, например: `u0_a139`
5. `passwd` - создать пароль для пользователя

На компьютере: `ssh <имя пользователя>@<ip> -p 8022`